# how to change method signature from void to CompletionStage<Void>?

Tags: java-8, future, completion-stage

```
class AnotherClass {

    Option<Integer> validateAndGetInt(Xyz xyz, Mno mno, String strValue) {
        if (strValue != null) {
           int intValue = 1;
           
           try{
              intValue = Integer.parseInt(strValue);
           } catch (Exception e) {
              throw new Exception("err");
           }
       
           Printer.getInstance().validateInt(xyz, mno, intValue);

           return Optional.of(intValue);
        }
    }
} // class ends

class Printer {
   void validateInt(Xyz xyz, Mno mno, int x) {
      int m = xyz.getTeamVal(mno, x);
      if(m < 0) {
          throw new CustomException("invalid team value");
      }
   }
}
```

I am planning to move from `void` to `CompletionStage<Void>` for `validate(int x)`.

`validate` will change as below, but I am not sure how to use in the calling side.

```
  CompletionStage<Void> validateInt(Xyz xyz, Mno mno, int x) {
      CompletableFuture<Void> f = new CompletableFuture<Void>();
      int m = xyz.getTeamVal(mno, x);
      if(m < 0) {
          f.completeExceptionally(new CustomException("invalid team value"));
      } else {
          f.complete(null);
      }
      return f;
   }
```

Can someone help explain how I can use it in `AnotherClass`?

I don't want to use this, as much as possible :

`Printer.getInstance().validateInt(xyz, mno, intValue).toCompletableFuture().get()`

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen? Using a `CompletionStage` really only makes sense if `validateInt` executes asynchronously.

Comment: @Slaw I have edited the question to update how `validateInt` will look like.

Comment: Still not sure why you want to use `CompletionStage` here. Your method never executes asynchronously and always returns an already-completed stage—what's the point?

Comment: are you saying this piece of code 
```
 CompletionStage<Void> validateInt(Xyz xyz, Mno mno, int x) {
      CompletableFuture<Void> f = new CompletableFuture<Void>();
      int m = xyz.getTeamVal(mno, x);
      if(m < 0) {
          f.completeExceptionally(new CustomException("invalid team value"));
      } else {
          f.complete(null);
      }
      return f;
   }
``` is not asynchronous? 

I'm sorry I don't quite understand your comment.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Your method is not asynchronous. It creates a stage, fetches a value, tests the value, completes the stage based on said test, and then returns the stage. The caller now has a completed `CompletionStage` which it must query to know if it failed or not. My question is: Why add that layer of indirection?

Comment: That said, I realize I'm questioning the premise of your question rather than answering it. If you want to avoid calling `toCompletableFuture().get()` then you need to call one of the other methods of `CompletionStage`. One option is `whenComplete[Async]` which is invoked when the triggering stage completes, whether successful or exceptional; you can test if the error is non-null to know if the validation failed. But I still question the wisdom of using `CompletionStage` in the first place (assuming your question adequately demonstrates your real code).